# How to create a dynamic checkbox- read only and checked values in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I am using a dynamic checkbox to show a seat allocation of a bus.  P3_TOTAL  value is calculated on page load and it gives  total number of seats. Seats are numbered as 1,2,3...and so on. The following query provides seat  number of  all seats :

```
  SELECT ROWNUM as n,ROWNUM as d
  FROM   ( SELECT 1 just_a_column
                 FROM   dual
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= :P3_TOTAL
               )
```

Following query shows  booked seats numbers :

```
SELECT
seat_no ,seat_no
FROM ticket_details
```

Only when a seat is booked, above table gets populated.

My question is : I want to show the seat allocation as a check box of column 2. Booked seats should be checked and read only. Rest of the seats should be open to select.